# Mailto display nothing in Android but work in iOS using IntelXDK

Tags: android, ios, intel-xdk

I currently developing one mobile applications using IntelXDK . 
I code the mailto function like this :

```js
<script>
  function openExternal(elem){
     window.open(elem.href,"_system");
     return false;
  }
</script>
```

```html
<a href="mailto:support@centracs.com.my" onclick="javascript:return openExternal(this)" class="icon location">Contact Us</a>
```

Unfortunatelly , its display different result for android and iOS platform .

[Android display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhHjh.png)

[iOS display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWGrN.png)

I hope someone can help me figure out this problem because i already do some research and untill now , i dont have the solution yet .

Thanks and Regrads.